# Unable to set the value of bound property in angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement a bound property for an angular component as explained in the [component documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) and [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview).

Unfortunately the values I'm assigning at the tag level or in the `$onInit` methods are never used. Nor is the value printed when I use it as a model value.

You can find the [full code on plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/looscjkyMo36IJQKTsRo).

My binding definition:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  function SearchResultController($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.searchFor = 'nohting-ctor';

    ctrl.$onInit = function() {
      console.log('SearchResultController.$onInit: searchFor='+ctrl.searchFor);
      ctrl.searchFor = 'nothing-int';
    };

  }

  angular.module('myApp').component('searchResult', {
    templateUrl: 'searchResult.html',
    controller: SearchResultController,
    bindings: {
      searchFor: '<'
    }
  });
})(window.angular);
```

Template:

```
<p>SearchResult for <span ng-model="$ctrl.searchFor"</span></span></p>
```

How it's used:

```
<h1>Main Window</h1>
<search-input on-start-search="$ctrl.startSearch(value)"></search-input>
<search-result search-for="nothing-ext"></search-result>
```

None of the `nothing-*` values is evers shown.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of you component is not correct. If you want to pass a string it should be quoted:

```
<search-result search-for="'nothing-ext'"></search-result>
```

Then next problem is that this line

```
<p>SearchResult for <span ng-model="$ctrl.searchFor"</span></span></p>
```

doesn't make sense, as ngModel directive is only valid for input controls. You want ngBind or simple `{{ $ctrl.searchFor }}`:

```html
<p>SearchResult for <span ng-bind="$ctrl.searchFor"</span></span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks. Saved my day! Is there any explanation about the expected syntax that has to go into bound properties value?

Comment: I sure you can find something about this in documentation. However, I can explain it in simple words. So you have 3 types of bindings and 2 types of what you can write as attribute value. Bindings: `=` two-way binding - accepts and expression, the value should look like normal JS code. That's why you can't write `{{ }}` as `=` expression, because it's not valid JS. `test: '@'` - value must be a string: `test="'quoted string'"` or `test="{{ someExpression }}"` because after parsing and evaluation of the template `{{ someExpression }}` will get expanded into string, same as `"'some string'"`.

Comment: `test: '&'` binding expects value to be something that can be invoked (as if it was a function) or passed to `eval` basically. So when you deal with `=` (or `<`) you need the value of the attribute to be a valid JS expression. Examples of valid expressions  (like in JS): `someObj`, `'some string'`, `someObj.prop`. Example of invalid expressions: `{{something}}`, `some/path.html` (that's why in ngInclude you need to quote path if it's a static string).